# How to load an HTML template when NGINX is down and or reloading?

Tags: templates, nginx

I'm trying to find a way to load an `html` that shows "Server Down" or something similar when I'm building my application.

Right now I every time I build my backend and frontend there are couple of seconds when I see the below template if I go to the site:

[image]

I will like to customize that page or show a different template saying : `Server Down at the moment` or `Building`

My `nginx.conf` is the following. Where should I put the location for a 403.html template to load ?: This needs to be outside of the build folder I think, since the 403 page appears while it's building.

```
 server {  # [ASK]: is this what's causing the problem ? 
root /home/smiling/smiling-frontend/website/build; ## development build
index index.html;

server_name frontend.develop.smiling.be;  ## development domain


charset  utf-8;
gzip on;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_disable "msie6";
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_min_length 1100;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types
  text/plain
  text/css
  text/js
  text/xml
  text/javascript
  application/javascript
  application/x-javascript
  application/json
  application/xml
  application/xml+rss;

location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc|svg|woff|woff2|ttf)\$ {
  expires 1M;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

location ~* \.(?:css|js)\$ {
  expires 7d;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
  
location ~ /\.well-known {
  allow all;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
  deny  all;
}

add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*/';
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'origin, x-requested-with, content-type, accept, authorization';
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST';



listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/backend.develop.smiling.be/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/backend.develop.smiling.be/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last sentence is kind of inconsistent... You like not to do something, but want to do the same thing nevertheless.

---

You could define your own page or string to be served on errors:

```
error_page 403 /403.html;

location = /403.html {
    internal;
    return 403 "Server Down at the moment"; # <- this could also contain an HTML string if your nginx defaults to text/html as content type.
}
```

You could also put a `403.html` file in your root folder and skip the location part in order to serve a full HTML file here.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the last sentence. It was indeed confusing. This settings, do you add them to the nginx config file or where exactly ? Thanks

Comment: You add this to your `nginx.conf` server block.

Comment: I updated my anwer with my nginx.conf. I would like to load a 403.html. But I'm having problems understanding on where to put it. Sorry for this, new to all this. I'm building a react app by the way.